# Showing loading indicator when loading data via AJAX on pagecreate event with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page which loads its content dynamically via AJAX on pagecreate event. I would like to show a loading indicator. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

My theory is that it doesn't work because the page loading itself shows loading indicator and hides it after the page is loaded:

- Page: show loading indicator
- AJAX: show loading indicator
- Page: hide loading indicator
- AJAX: hide loading indicator

Has anyone succeeded with keeping the loading indicator displayed even after the actual page has been loaded but the AJAX data has not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, u need to run this in **pageshow** event, to show the loading indicator. In **pagecreate the loader can't show up**.

Then on AJAX call, hide the loader on complete: like this-

```
function getAllData()
{
        //$.mobile.pageLoading();  //for old jqm versions
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        $.ajax({
           url : "sample.com/path/to/file",
           success : function (data) {
                     $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
           },
           complete : function () {
                      //$.mobile.pageLoading(true);  //for old jqm versions
                      $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
           },
           error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert("Error text :"+textStatus+ " - type :" + errorThrown+" - Error message :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
                   //$.mobile.pageLoading(true);  //for old jqm versions
                   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
           }
        });
}
```

-then it should work.